# Per-domain page caching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have an app that hosts several accounts, each mapped to its own domain.

I want to define different page caching directories for each account.

I have this in my application controller (before filter):

```
self.page_cache_directory = RAILS_ROOT+"/public/cache/" + @account.name
```

But that doesn't seem right because it effectively overwrites the page_cache_directory variable for ActionController::Base (it is a cattr_accessor), being a problem with concurrent requests.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try in your app controller:

```
def the_before_filter
  @account = Account.find(...)
  (class << self; self; end).instance_eval { define_method :cache_page do |content, path|
     super content, @account.name + path
  end
  }
end
```

resources:

http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html

http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html

Comment: That shouldn't work, should it?: it's a class method but @account is an instance variable.

Comment: This code is not working? `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`